# Swift: how to know if annotation is inside a cluster?

Tags: swift, mapkit

i have a view with a mapview and a collection view. They are connected so,
if i tap on annotation, the collection scroll to the connected cell and vice versa, if i scroll the collection, when the scroll ends, the map highlight the corresponding annotation.

The annotations are clustered and this is a problem because when scroll stops, if the annotation is inside a cluster, isn't impossible to highlight it.

To solve the problem i set func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView), inside the func i zoom in at the annotation coordinate but there is another problem, if two annotations are too close the map maintain the cluster and it's impossible separate the pins.

And now some question:

- is it possible verify if an annotation is inside a cluster?
- is it possible to set the distance between two points for clustering?
- is it possible to identify a cluster on map?

I just need to understand what is the way and then start studying :-)

Thank you in advance for any suggestion